# Calling a rest api from a C# client

Tags: c#, rest, client

using c#.

I just want to clarify something...  I normally work with WCF. Can I call rest apis exactly like I call WCF? Or do I use WebClient and parse the responseStream?  If the rest api returns string formatted as JSON would I then somehow format this json in the responseStream?

I have spent sometime Googling but there seems to be different advice for it.

to be specific are there any standards for rest api clients?  Is it just down to choice?

Comment: A simple Google search for "call rest api .net" gives you this: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client Seems fairly obvious to me.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Hi, thanks for the link. This it what I mean. I have seen samples using webclient and I have seen links such as the 1 you kindly sent me...

Comment: @Closer - Will try to be more specific in my question...

Comment: @downvoter (I did expect to be down voted on this question) I am trying to establish what are the standards in using rest api clients

Comment: @JustinNiessner you or may not have down voted me but the link you gave was a good alternative to the answer I accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) (For making REST calls) and [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json) (For serializing / deserializing your json):

A simple `Get` request:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

//will throw an exception if not successful
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(content);
```

Note `HttpClient` is built with an asynchronous API which preferably should be used with [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords

Comment: Hi, I believe this is what I am after. This parallels what I do when I call a WebmMethod using jquery. The SomeType (my class object) was what I was after. Thanks

Comment: HI - thanks. Will accept as answer when I am given permission to do :)

Comment: This is a one-liner with [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl), which uses HttpClient and Json.NET under the hood: `var result = await uri.GetJsonAsync<SomeType>();`

Comment: You can of course use DataContractJsonSerializer in .NET 4.5 to serialize/deserialize your json.

Comment: Shameless plug but https://github.com/DalSoft/DalSoft.RestClient wraps it all up in one fluent call including serialization/deserialization without generics. 

dynamic client = new RestClient("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");

await client.Posts().Get(1);